# Manually connecting to database in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlclient

Is it possible to manually connect to the database using sqlclient and sqlconnection (ie standard ADO.net way) instead of using LINQ or Entity Framework in Asp.Net MVC?

Please guide me
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Nothing magic about MVC in that regard.  Just create your connection and command the way you would have in the past in your action method and fill your DataTable.

Comment: Could you please give me an updated answer as I've edited the question?
Thanks