# odbc instructions to connect to oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, odbc

I am trying to connect to an oracle database from my website (asp.net-mvc).  The only information i have to connect to the database is ODBC instructions which tells me to go:

1. It says to go into an oracle directory on the machine and enter this into a `TSNNames.ora` file and enter this in:

   ```
   DBNAME=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=[machine])(port=[port]))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=[DBNAME])))
   ```
2. and then go to control panel and manually add a connection through the GUI wizard.

Is there anyway i can connect to this database without have to set this up?  I was hoping to simply stick a connection string in and be on my way.   I deploy to different machines and i dont want the burden of having to update the .ora files or walk through this GUI wizard setup.

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Comment: NOTE: SID=DBNAME, not your username.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use ODBC. [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) is a driver provided by Oracle which is based on the same model as SQL Server: simply download the assembly, reference it in your project and use it:

```
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Some connection string"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
       conn.Open();
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM foo";
       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
             int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: See [this stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client) for details on the minimal set of libraries required for distribution.

Answer (score 2):

According to a similar question, [Manually connecting to database in Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353921/manually-connecting-to-database-in-asp-net-mvc), there's no magic involved.  Just connect to the db as you normally would.

There's a VB example @ http://www.aspdev.org/articles/asp.net-mysql-connect/  It's for MySql but should be simple enough to switch to your Oracle connection string.

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote?  Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I thought it was a fair enough answer

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one ado.net provider for Oracle that doesn't require an Oracle client on the machine. See http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/. Devart calls this feature 'direct mode'. This Oracle specific provider will also probably perform much better than an odbc provider.

But there is something I don't understand? You have build an asp.net mvc application so you only have to install on a server. So what is the problem?